# Include multiple JavaScript before the code runs in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I want to include multiple javascript in PhantomJS. page.includeJS / page.injectJS does not show up option to include multiple scripts. Can you provide a working example for the same?

Code:

```
page.open('index.html', function (openStatus) {
  console.log("OPen Status is "+openStatus)
  if(openStatus == 'success') {
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', function(jStatus) {
      console.log("Jquery status: "+jStatus)
      (page.includeJs('jquery.textillate.js', function(tStatus) {
        console.log("Text status: "+tStatus)
        (page.evaluate(function () {
          var tag = document.getElementById("main-tag")
          tag.innerHTML = "Hello World"
          document.getElementById("main-tag").textillate({ 
            maxDisplayTime: 2000,
            in: { effect: 'fadeInUp',
            delay: 7000 } 
          });
          console.log('Textilate is: '+tag) 
        }))
      }))
    })
    // setInterval(function() {
    //   page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: "png" });
    //   if( frames == 0 ){
    //       phantom.exit();
    //   }
    //   frames--;
    // }, 40);
  }
});
```

Error:
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.getElementById("main-tag").textillate({

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @AGoranov Just not able to load multiple JS files. This is the error 
 
"TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.getElementById("main-tag").textillate({ "

Trying to use texillate.js which requires jQuery.

Comment: @Cerbrus My question is to include multiple JS files and inject not just one

Comment: So? What's the problem? What's stopping you from including multiple files using the method described in the dupe target?

Comment: @Cerbrus The script is just not loading. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: _"The script is just not loading."_? What makes you think that is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164040/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-cerbrus).

Answer (score -1):

`undefined is not a constructor` means that you're calling a method that is not defined. Most probably `jquery.textillate.js` isn't available to the target page, because judging by the code samle it's a local script, and for that to use in page.evaluate you should use [page.injectJs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) method.

To also answer another question of yours: there's a simpler way to inject multiple scripts. Just put them all in one bundled local script and inject it.